# jQuery + Ajax solution for "browsing" very large files

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, large-files

I've got some potentially very large (multiple GB) text files that I'd like to be able to view within a div.

In concept it's not hard... make an AJAX request for a more sensibly sized chunk of file, the AJAX script (PHP would be nice) seeks to an intelligent position within the file, and sends me what I need, which is then rendered vis JS in to an element.

This can't be a new problem, and I'm hoping someone else has already solved it.

Is there such a bit of Javascript (jQuery preferably) with related server scripts already out there somewhere?

Comment: maybe partially useable http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html > New in version 3.6 > True scrolling Rows

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any library which does this. But it shouldn't be too hard doing yourself. The server side is almost trivial:

```
<?php
$chunkSize = $_GET['chunksize'];
$offset = $_GET['offset'];

$handle = fopen("text_file.txt", "r");
fseek($handle, $offset);
$chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSize);
fclose($handle);
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo $chunk;
?>
```

This is without any error handling, but that shouldn't be too much hassle as well.

Now, for the client side, there are of course some subtleties, as you will need to have two chunks in the text field at once in order to provide a "smooth" experience, but it should be doable.